# Class import is not working on gitlabci with cypress

Tags: automation, cypress, gitlab-ci

in my cypress script i'm importing files as i'm doing page object models like this

```
import { LoginPage } from '../../page-objects/admin/login-page/LoginPage'
import {Common} from '../../page-objects/common/Common'
```

But my test fail on gitlab as it tries to import from another directory

```
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module '../../page-objects/common/Common' from '/builds/user/project_name/cypress/integration/landing-page/login.js'
    required by /builds/user/project_name/cypress/integration/landing-page/login.js
```

My test is running smoothly on local but not on gitlabci

For more info here's my project architecture :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [import statements are case-insensitive on Mac and Windows but case-sensitive on Linux](https://briandesousa.net/?p=870#:%7E:text=It%20turns%20out%20that%20import,There%20is%20a%20forceConsistentCasingInFileNames%20tsconfig.).

Since Gitlab is running [linux](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/package_information/supported_os.html), try matching the file name exactly

```js
import {Common} from '../../page-objects/common/common'
```